# How to prove that a curve is contained in a hyperplane?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves

As stated in this question: [A curve is contained in a hyperplane if and only if $\kappa_{n-1} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513825/a-curve-is-contained-in-a-hyperplane-if-and-only-if-kappa_n-1-0)

I'm learning differential geometry by myself and is now trying to prove that a curve of  $\mathbb{R^n}$ is contained in a hyperplane if and only if $κ_{n−1}=0$, however I'm also not sure how to proceed.

There is a hint in the page 17 of this pdf, saying that "From above it is easy to see that a Frenet curve in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is contained in a hyperplane if and only if $κ_{n−1}\equiv 0$", but I cannot see why, can someone explain it to me, or just give me some hint?

https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1516/math4030/4030LectureNotesPart1.pdf

Comment: I think you mean $\kappa_{n-1}=0$. Besides, have a look on the text I have tried to better (by enclosing formulas between dollar signs etc...) for next time you ask a question.

Comment: Posted an answer at [A curve is contained in a hyperplane if and only if $\kappa_{n-1} = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513825).

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang your answer is fantastic, I'm just a little bit lost when you mention ⟨γ(s)−γ(0),en⟩≡0. Where does γ(s)−γ(0) come from?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Hi Andrew. How to you know that ∫s0⟨γ′(t),en⟩dt = 0? Show en be en-1, since we are talking about the hyperplane? How do you show that the distance of the osculating hyperplane from the origin are constant? Sorry for so many following questions, I'm still trying to get myself familiar with all the notations.

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Great, that helps a lot. (Actually I keep asking you questions under my post because I don't have enough reputation to comment others' post haha. ) Just one final question, does ⟨γ(s)−γ(0),en⟩≡0 shows that the distance from the osculating hyperplane to the origin is 0?

Comment: (Ah, I'd forgotten the need for 50 rep before commenting.) It's not the distance to the origin that's constant, but the "component along $\mathbf{e}_{n}$" (or the "height") that's constant; this condition defines a hyperplane.